# C# Processing same object with different "processors" a flyweight pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, tree, flyweight-pattern

I've been doing a lot of research on different design patterns and I'm trying to determine the correct way of doing this.

I have an image uploading MVC app that I'm developing which needs to process the image in several different ways, such as create a thumbnail and save a database record. Would the best way to approach this be via a flyweight pattern? Using this as an example:

```
var image = new Image();    

List<IProcessors> processors = processorFactory.GetProcessors(ImageType.Jpeg);

foreach(IProcessor processor in processors)
{
    processor.process(image);
}
```

I have second part to this question as well. What if the processor has smaller related "sub-processors"? An example that I have in my head would be a book generator.

```
I have a book generator 
     that has page generators
          that has paragraph generators
               that has sentence generators
```

Would this be a flyweight pattern as well? How would I handle the traversal of that tree?

**EDIT**

I asked this question below but I wanted to add it here:

All the examples that I've see of the composite pattern seems to relate to handling of values while the flyweight pattern seems to deal with processing (or sharing) of an object's state. Am I just reading into the examples too much? Would combining the patterns be the solution?

Comment: Yo dawg. I heard you like things inside of things, so I got you a composite inside of a composite so you can composite composites! (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: `Would combining the patterns be the solution?` Yup that's called architecture. Patterns themselves don't solve problems in and of themselves, they're just ways of approaching the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I, unfortunately, work in an environment where studying patterns is considered a waste of time. I wanted to ask this question to make sure my head was headed in the right direction

Comment: `I, unfortunately, work in an environment where studying patterns is considered a waste of time.` Hah. I totally understand. The only "waste of time" is the enormous amount of time wasted because the code is not refactored into any sort of meaningful architecture, where the whole code-base inevitably becomes 'write only'

Comment: Having a sequential set of processors process your data in place is closer to a Visitor Pattern. However, processing with the intent of creating side-effects (saving a thumbnail to the db, etc.) is not a Visitor. Your example has some qualities of Chain Of Responsibility and Command patterns, but it is neither.

Comment: I guess I considered it a flyweight because the same image object being used across multiple processor objects . But after re-reading the Visitor pattern I can see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can at least handle the second part of the question. To expand a tree (or a composite), use simple recursion.

```
void Recursion(TreeItem parent) 
{
    // First call the same function for all the children.
    // This will take us all the way to the bottom of the tree.
    // The foreach loop won't execute when we're at the bottom.
    foreach (TreeItem child in parent.Children) 
    {
         Recursion(child);
    }
    
    // When there are no more children (since we're at the bottom)
    // then finally perform the task you want. This will slowly work
    // it's way up the entire tree from bottom most items to the top.
    Console.WriteLine(parent.Name);
}
```

Comment: All the examples that I've see of the composite pattern seems to relate to handling of values while the flyweight pattern seems to deal with processing (or sharing) of an object's state. Am I just reading into the examples too much?

Comment: Composite is used for building things like trees (think tree-views or menu items where you have sub-items that are the same as their parent). You use recursion to unravel a tree/composite (look up: "depth first search"). Flyweights are for things like caches, where you reuse the same stuff, just in different contexts. For example, a text editor only loads the images for a font once, then you just reuse the glyphs when you meet a particular character code. It wouldn't make sense to keep using independent images when rendering the text, so you cache the images and reuse them - flyweight.

Comment: One more question, if I may. Is it considered "acceptable" for the children to be a different type? A subtype?

Comment: Yeah of course. In fact the GoF book that originally compiled these patterns together emphasizes programming against the 'Interface' not against the 'Implementation', because it will make your code not as reliant on the specific implementation used. The upshot of this is that you would have to have some sort of subclassing involved, but in general you would try to program (as much as possible) against base classes/interfaces, not against the derived (where it can be helped).

Answer (score 1):

What your describing could have some flyweights representing each of those nested classes. But in this case that would be more of an implementation detail. In my experience, flyweights are usually called for at the architectural level or implementation level but rarely as an element of design.

Consider this class -

```
public interface IMyData {
    IdType MyId { get; }
    byte[] BlobData { get; }
    long SizeOfBlob { get; }
}
public class MyData : IMyData {
    public IdType MyId { get; private set; }
    public byte[] BlobData { get; set; }
    public long SizeOfBlob { get { return BlobData.LongLength; } }
    }
}
```

In your multi-tiered application, this object needs to travel from the source database, to a manager's IPhone for approval based on the blob size, and then to an accounting system for billing. So instead of transporting the whole thing to the IPhone App, you substitute the flyweight:

```
public class MyDataFlyWeight : IMyData {
    public MyDataFlyWeight(IdType myId, long blobSize){
        MyId = myId;
        BlobSize = blobSize;
    }
    public IdType MyId { get; set; }
    public byte[] MutableBlobData { get { 
            throw new NotImplmentedException();
            }
        }
    public long BlobSize { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

By having both implement `IMyData` and by building the system with the interface and not the concrete type (you did this, right?!), then you could use `MyDataFlyweight` objects from the IPhone App and `MyData` objects in the rest of the system. All you have to do is properly initialize `MyDataFlyweight` with the blob size.

The architecture which calls for an IPhone App would dictate that a flyweight is used within the IPhone App.

In addition, consider the newer `Lazy<T>` class:

```
public class MyData : IMyData {
    public IdType MyId { get; private set; }

    private Lazy<byte[]> _blob = new Lazy<byte[]>(() => 
                                 StaticBlobService.GetBlob(MyId));
    public byte[] BlobData { get { return _blob.Value; } }
    public long SizeOfBlob { get { return BlobData.LongLength; } }
    }
}
```

This is an example of using the flyweight purely as an implementation detail.